# Aforge and CyberLink YouCam , camera not start

Tags: c#, camera, aforge

I work on project that capture an images from webcams using C# and Aforge.

When the camera is a 'CyberLink' i get this frame from the camera:

[image]

The code that you see here is only part of my code of course, but it demonstrates my use in Aforge.

Get all cams on this PC:

```
var webCam = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
var cams = new List<VideoCaptureDevice>();

foreach (FilterInfo camInfo in webCam)
{
   var cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(camInfo.MonikerString);
   cam.NewFrame += NewFrameHandler;
   cams.Add(cam);
}
```

I have a timer that every few minutes starts the camera like this:

```
foreach (var cam in cams)
{
    cam.Start();
}
```

When i get the event 'NewFrame' i call to my function 'NewFrameHandler' to save the frame and close the camera:

```
var bit = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
bit.Save("@c:\Cam_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);

foreach (var cam in cams)
{
    cam.SignalToStop();
}
```

As i say the code works great, only when the camera is CyberLink i have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the youcam software and now I get the frames properly.
Would love to hear if anyone has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The YouCam software may hijack the stream, and removing it may be the only option. You could also check if YouCam offers an API of its own that allows you to interface with the camera. I have used AForge before and it worked great with the Logitech cameras I was using. Your code looks good to me, though it was a year or two ago when I was using AForge.